# SharePoint 2007: what happens to hyperlinks when moving a subsite?

Tags: 2007, site, hyperlink, move

If moving a site in SharePoint 2007 (using the Manage Content and Structure function) to a new location, do the internal links get corrupted?

I know that some links do tend to get broken in these kinds of moves, but if the links are only to files and folders within the site that is moved, what happens?

Do the links somehow understand the new location automatically - is it even relevant what the site collection is when the links are only inside the sub site in question?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the links and how they were originally generated.  SharePoint managed links, and relative links will work fine.  Hard coded links will break.